# google app engine: go to login page by javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

Do anyone know how do use javascript to redirect user login using Google Accounts?

I know there is "`users.create_login_url(self.request.path)`" but how do that integrated to "`window.location"

Or there is alternative??

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass the string that is created by *users.create_login_url(self.request.path)* to your template as a template variable, and then the template variable can be inserted into your Javascript with double curly braces (if you are using the bundled Django templates):

```
window.location = {{ authention_url }}
```

where **authentication_url** is the template variable that you created in your RequestHandler.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I dont even know that `users.create_login_url(self.request.path)` will generate a string, simply print it out will do.